# Why does the back button work even when using WillPopScope in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my code, there is an automatically popup dialog box. I need to prevent my user from being able to click on the back button when this popup appears.

Here is the whole code:

```dart
// New Game route
class NewGameRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewGameRoute({key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'New Game',
      home: ListFromCSV(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState createState() => _ListFromCSVState();
}

class _ListFromCSVState extends State<ListFromCSV> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;
  String assetPath = "files/main.jpg";
  bool shouldPop = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);
    assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == ""
        ? "files/main.jpg"
        : _listData[_listCount][1];
  }

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      assetPath =
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
      _listData[_listCount][2] == "" ? null : _showAlertDialog();
    });
  }

  // This function makes buttons visible/invisible
  bool isVisible = true; //will be visible for the first frame

  void _isVisible() {
    setState(() {
      isVisible = !isVisible;
    });
  }


  //Alert Dialog about questions and answers
  void _showAlertDialog() {

    // set up the buttons
    Widget Answer1Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][3]),
      onPressed:  () {},
    );
    Widget Answer2Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][4]),
      onPressed:  () {},
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      // title: Text(),
      content: Text(_listData[_listCount][2]),
      actions: [
        Answer1Button,
        Answer2Button,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,  //use to dismiss any tap on the background of the dialog
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          // await showDialog or Show add banners or whatever
          // return true if the route to be popped
          return false; // return false if you want to disable device back button click
        },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('New Game'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Visibility(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Positioned.fill(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        ImageButton(label: 'OK', onButtonTap: _nextCSV),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Test1', onButtonTap: _showAlertDialog),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                visible: isVisible,
              ),
              // your other widgets
              Visibility(
                child: ImageButton(label: 'Show', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                visible: !isVisible,
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the part that wraps the Scaffold:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          // await showDialog or Show add banners or whatever
          // return true if the route to be popped
          return false; // return false if you want to disable device back button click
        },
      child: Scaffold(
```

But the back button still works and cancels the dialog box. What's my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return false;
          },
          child: Container(
            //Your popup's content goes here
          ));
      }
)
```

Comment: What part of my code should I replace with this? I am a newbie, so I'm afraid to mess up something that somehow works.

Comment: Just put the content that you want to show inside the popup where I've written "Your popup's content goes here". Put this inside a function (say A) and call it on any event that you would want to (e.g., onPressed : ( ) => A( )). If this is something that needs to comeup after you load a page, simply put it inside Future.delayed(
                      Duration.zero,
                      () => A()) and put it anywhere inside your build and you're done!

Comment: Thank you. This is a good alternative to what I have already done. But at the moment I have another question. WillPopScope doesn't work in my code for some reason. Although when I recreate the example from the documentation, everything works there.

Comment: Well, it would work if you would return WillPopScope inside the dialog box. Right now you've added it to your page and not to your popup dialog.

Comment: To be honest, at first I also tried to add it there. Unsuccessfully, though. But then I asked a question here. And I received an answer for modifying exactly that part of the code. I don't know why those people gave me such advice.

Comment: I've been using it in my code without any issues and it works like a charm.

Comment: I believe you. I took your code as a basis and corrected my part with showDialog. And now it works exactly as I need it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. Happy coding :)